Get first and last values from long table by permutation based on date
I'm currently working on this file, which lists administrative events that have occurred in communes (local authorities) since 1943 in France.
I'm interested in the variables DATE_EFF, COM_AV and COM_AP, and more particularly in the observations where COM_AV is different than COM_AP:
data <- 
  readr::read_csv("v_mvt_commune_2024.csv") |>
  dplyr::select(DATE_EFF, COM_AV, COM_AP) |>
  dplyr::filter(COM_AV != COM_AP)

Here is a sample of 10 rows:



"DATE_EFF"
"COM_AV"
"COM_AP"




1973-01-01
"64031"
"64113"


1968-01-01
"78675"
"95675"


2017-01-01
"86030"
"86281"


2002-09-01
"07021"
"07207"


2005-01-01
"52359"
"52495"


1969-12-01
"25423"
"25138"


1973-01-01
"79232"
"79123"


1973-04-01
"70209"
"70528"


2014-04-17
"05002"
"05139"


1977-11-15
"64113"
"64031"



Each commune may have undergone a number of changes during this period.
For example, in the sample above, we can see that:

64031 became 64113 in 1973-01-01
64113 became 64031 in 1977-11-15

I'd like to have a table where COM_AV contains the first value and COM_AP contains the last value as such:



"COM_AV"
"COM_AP"




"64031"
"64031"



This supposes that multiple COM_AV can point to the same COM_AP and of course, COM_AV is not always the same as COM_AP.
What would be the most efficient way to solve this problem using tidyverse?

Consider treating this as a graph problem.

@Friede, I think I've figured out how to solve this problem with an iteration as suggested in the solution below.

I tried to solve this problem on my own after posting this question and here is my current proposition:
data <- 
  readr::read_csv("v_mvt_commune_2024.csv") |>
  dplyr::select(DATE_EFF, COM_AV, COM_AP) |>
  dplyr::group_by(COM_AV) |>
  dplyr::filter(DATE_EFF == max(DATE_EFF)) |>
  dplyr::ungroup() |>
  dplyr::arrange(DATE_EFF, COM_AV)

dates <-
  data |>
  dplyr::arrange(DATE_EFF) |>
  dplyr::distinct(DATE_EFF) |>
  dplyr::pull()

res <- 
  data |>
  dplyr::filter(DATE_EFF == dplyr::first(dates)) |>
  dplyr::select(!DATE_EFF)

for (i in 2:length(dates)) {
  curr_data <-
    data |>
    dplyr::filter(DATE_EFF == dplyr::nth(dates, n = i)) |>
    dplyr::select(!DATE_EFF)
  
  res <-
    res |>
    dplyr::full_join(curr_data, dplyr::join_by(COM_AP == COM_AV)) |>
    dplyr::mutate(
      COM_AV = dplyr::if_else(!is.na(COM_AV), COM_AV, COM_AP),
      COM_AP = dplyr::if_else(!is.na(COM_AP.y), COM_AP.y, COM_AP)
    ) |>
    dplyr::select(!dplyr::contains("."))
  
  # If two communes merge and split again, keep only the original value
  eq <-
    res |>
    dplyr::filter(COM_AV == COM_AP) |>
    dplyr::distinct(COM_AV) |>
    dplyr::pull()
  
  # If join_by conditions are matched, add the corresponding lines to res as well
  com_ap_after_join <-
    res |>
    dplyr::distinct(COM_AP) |>
    dplyr::arrange() |>
    dplyr::pull()
  
  to_bind <-
    curr_data |>
    dplyr::filter(COM_AP %in% com_ap_after_join)
  
  res <-
    res |>
    dplyr::filter((COM_AV %in% eq & COM_AV == COM_AP) | !COM_AV %in% eq) |>
    dplyr::bind_rows(to_bind)
}

res <-
  res |>
  dplyr::filter(COM_AV != COM_AP) |>
  dplyr::distinct() |>
  dplyr::arrange(COM_AV)


Your result contains more rows than the original data. Shouldn't it contain the number of unique values in COM_AV?

@Edward, excellent point, I think it's because of dplyr::full_join(). I have 5338 rows if I do res <- dplyr::distinct(res) which is less than the original number of unique values of COM_AV in data. I've updated the above code accordingly.

ok - but your result still contains duplicates for COM_AV. For example, "01003", but I noticed that the original data have duplicates as well. I have ignored these while you haven't. I also found a row in the data that you didn't find: COM_AV=="01091". while my code finds it. So, our results still differ. I am not saying that my code is correct, just that our results differ.

@Edward, thanks for the heads up, I'll check out why they differ and get back to you with more details if I can figure it out.

@Edward, I agree that your solution was finally more concise and elegant, but our discussion made me realize two exceptions that had to be taken into account in my own code. Firstly, if two communes merge and split again, you only need to keep the original value. For example, x -> a & y -> a and after a -> x & a -> y, then x -> x & y -> y. One should also add the rows for which the join worked, this is why COM_AV == "01091" did not show up in the previous version. I've updated the above code accordingly, thanks again for your comments!

With a reasonably small dataset, one way is to use iteration.
f <- function(data) {
  # Create a minimum data
  data_1 <- slice_min(data, DATE_EFF, by=COM_AV, with_ties=FALSE, n=1)

  for(i in 1:nrow(data_1)) {
    AP <- data_1$COM_AP[i]
    
    # Find rows in the whole data containing this AP value in COM_AV
    AP_2 <- filter(data, COM_AV==AP) 

    # While rows exist in the data with COM_AV containing this AP value
    while(nrow(AP_2)>0) {  
      # Find the row with the minimum value for DATE_EFF
      AP_2 <- slice_min(AP_2, DATE_EFF, by=COM_AV, with_ties=FALSE, n=1)
      
      # Save the date
      DATE_EFF <- pull(AP_2, DATE_EFF)
      
      # update COM_AP with the last value found
      data_1$COM_AP[i] <- pull(AP_2, COM_AP)

      # Try to find another
      AP_2 <- filter(data, COM_AV==AP & DATE_EFF>DATE_EFF)
    }
  }
  data_1
}


data_2 <- f(data)

filter(data_2, COM_AV=="64031")


# A tibble: 1 × 3
  DATE_EFF   COM_AV COM_AP
  <date>     <chr>  <chr> 
1 1973-01-01 64031  64031


Thanks a lot @Edward, I found a pretty similar solution myself in the meantime, but your post reminded me to use dplyr::slice_min() the next time!

Also @Edward, if you have any suggestions for a recursive solution, I'd be interested to hear them!
